# pandas find number of unique elements in each column of huge csv

Tags: csv, pandas, bigdata

I have a huge csv file around 10 GB and I get an error if I try to load in memory.

I need to compute the number of unique elements for each column of the dataframe. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could load each col in turn and then call `.nunique`:

```
In [227]:

import io
t="""a,b,c
0,1,1
0,2,1
1,3,1
2,4,1
3,5,6"""
# get the columns first
cols = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), nrows=1).columns
​
d = {}
for col in cols:
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t), usecols=col)
    d[col] = df[col].nunique()
d
Out[227]:
{'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 2}
```

this should then generate a dicts of the number of unique values for each columns

This assumes that you can handle loading a single column at a time from your 10GB file

Comment: I was trying to do this but the time to load each column is quiet big and I have 2000 columns :(

Comment: Well you could step through the columns at 100 at a time or something

Comment: I know that it is possible to read a dataframe in chunks. I am wondering if it is possible to use the `apply_along_axis`  on a dataframe that is only partially read into memory

Comment: You could use the chunking but it will be more complicated as you have to use a counter for each column I guess and `+=` for each chunk. I think reading 100 cols at a time should not be too bad but I don't have your data

Comment: Still surprises me that you cannot do `df.nunique()`!!